# Rails 3 database query has many through link

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a ***posts*** table and a ***tags*** table joined through a ***tagging*** table (Rails 3)

I would like to search for a keyword in the **Posts** **name** field and also any associated tags.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base             
    has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :tags, :through => :taggings

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :posts, :through => :taggings

class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :tag



var = "word"
Post.where("name LIKE ?","%#{var}%")
```

This will search the name field but I have no idea where to start to also search for Posts with a Tag matching "var"?

Do I have to do 2 separate searches one for Posts and one for Tags or can they be joined into one search somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Post.includes(:tags).where(["posts.name LIKE (?) AND tags.tag LIKE (?)", "%#{var}%", "%#{var}%"])
```

Comment: @fl00r Hey i know this is old but where do you define this? In the posts model?

Comment: @fl00r Cool, about to embark on a large rails app using searches through relational databases so ill be seeing you on the message boards soon!

Answer (score 0):

This should work at least in Rails 3

```
Post.joins(:tags).where('tags.name LIKE ?', "%#{var}%")
```